# Why my virtual environments are hidden created by 'mkvirtualenv'?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Whenever I create any virtual environment using `mkvirtualenv envname`, it creates the env and activate it automatically. But I can't find the folder named envname. Whenever I do `workon envname` it activates it, but I can't see the virtual environment folder.
Below is the packages I've installed.

```
Django==2.0.4
pbr==4.0.2
pytz==2018.4
six==1.11.0
stevedore==1.28.0
virtualenv==15.2.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed virtualenvwrapper using the provided instructions then you can find the directory using:

```
echo $WORKON_HOME
```

Any virtual environments are created in this directory.

Comment: I installed it using `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`.What do you mean by "Any virtual environments are created in this directory." Can you please make it a bit more clear?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari: when you run `mkvirtualenv envname` it'll create a directory called `envname` (the virtual environment) in the directory that is displayed when you run `echo $WORKON_HOME`.

Comment: When I do ` echo $WORKON_HOME` it simply returns $WORKON_HOME
By entering `where mkvirtualenv` it gives me the installation directory, but there is no envname directory.